# Made changes on a feature branch after it was already merged to master

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a feature branch that another dev merged into master and I spent the last 2 hours still adding commits to the feature branch before knowing the feature branch was merged earlier already.  What is the best way to get these new changes from feature branch into master?  Should I just make a new feature branch and add the changes to that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do what we call git rebase.

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase master
```

These two commands will bring all changes made in the feature branch to your master branch.

Rebase is another way to incorporate changes from one branch into another. I suggest you to read more about it online to make sure you use it effectively because it has its pros and cons.

Here is a good link regarding git merge and rebase commands:[git rebase](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-git-merge-and-rebase-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-131b863785f)

Answer (score 0):

If the feature branch is already merged in to the master and you still have some commits in your local feature branch, it's not a problem at all. Here's what you can do to push your latest changes in master:

1. Take latest master branch
2. Merge master with your local feature branch. Resolve conflicts if any.
3. Your feature branch is now up to date and ready to be merged in to master. Push Feature branch to remote.
4. Raise a PR from feature to master or do a merge manually.

Commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout featureBranch
git merge master
git push
```

Raise a PR from featureBranch to master OR merge feature branch with master manually like below:

```
git checkout master
git merge featureBranch
git push
```

Comment: thanks!  To be more precise, my feature branch is already merged into a 'release' branch that is prepped to go to master shortly.  Another developer controls the release branch so would they have to "re-pull" the feature branch into the release branch?

Comment: @herkypam You should be able to just open a new pull request (I think).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wish but where I'm working now doesn't use PR's -- only terminal commands

Comment: If your branch has already been merged with release and release will go in to master then you won't have to worry. Your changes will automatically go in to master once the release branch goes in to master.